# Create a periodic table in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

For my app, I need to create a [periodic table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#mediaviewer/File:Periodic_table_(polyatomic).svg). 
At the beginning, I thought to do a tablelayout and fill it dynamically with specific Views representing each element from a json file. But, I learnt that normally dynamic views are when we don't know exactly the number of Views, and the layout adapt itself to this unknow number.

But in my case, I know how the number of views and where to display them.

So: what do you advice me? is it possible to make a layout with about 100 element in it?
My questions are more relative to the best pratices in android and the best way to optimise the memory.
Thanks

Comment: I think a dynamic layout is a great idea because it allows you to read the data from JSON or whatever format you want rather than hardcoding it in your XML layout or resource files.

Comment: My approach would be to use nested Linear Layouts to build all the rows/columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements of the periodic table are known, I would recommend converting each row into a LinearLayout with TextView's in it. For all those places where there are no elements, convert it into a Space view or just a plain View. Make sure you you set the width of each TextView to 0dp and assign a weight to it; so that they space out evenly.

It would end up like

```
<LinearLayout orientation=vertical width=match_parent height=match_parent>
    <LinearLayout orientation=horizontal width=match_parent height=wrap_content>
        <TextView width=0dp, height=wrap_content, weight=<> text=Element-Name/>
        <Space width=0dp, height=wrap_content, weight=<>/>
        <TextView width=0dp, height=wrap_content, weight=<> text=Element-Name>
    </LinearLayout>

    .. another linearlayout similar to the above one for each row of the periodic table

</LinearLayout>
```

Another approach would be to create a custom view; a view that takes into consideration a single row with elements in it.

Yet another approach is to consider the GridView, provided you want to load the contents from the json file.

Comment: Your answer seems to be similar that clever_trevor's one. In my case, I don't need only 1 textview per element, so I will make custom view. But what I don't understand is why you put width to 0dp, and why it's better than doing several tablerows in a tablelayout?